# ffmpeg + libfdk_aac + vbr => wrong "BitRate_Mode"

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, bitrate

I'm trying to encode sample video clip or audio track with `ffmpeg` and `libfdk_aac` with variable bitrate mode`-vbr 3`:

```bash
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -crf 21 -vcodec h264 -acodec libfdk_aac -vbr 3 -ac 2 out.mp4
ffmpeg -i sample.mp3 -acodec libfdk_aac -vbr 3 -ac 2 out.m4a
```

`mediainfo` always shows

```
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
```

It sounds like a bug, isn't it?

Also, Mp4info looks like

```
File:
  major brand:      M4A 
  minor version:    200
  compatible brand: M4A 
  compatible brand: isom
  compatible brand: iso2
  fast start:       no

Movie:
  duration:   229042 ms
  time scale: 1000
  fragments:  no

Found 1 Tracks
Track 1:
  flags:        3 ENABLED IN-MOVIE
  id:           1
  type:         Audio
  duration: 229042 ms
  language: und
  media:
    sample count: 9864
    timescale:    44100
    duration:     10100736 (media timescale units)
    duration:     229042 (ms)
    bitrate (computed): 88.674 Kbps
  Sample Description 0
    Coding:      mp4a (MPEG-4 Audio)
    Stream Type: Audio
    Object Type: MPEG-4 Audio
    Max Bitrate: 88674
    Avg Bitrate: 88674
    Buffer Size: 0
    Codecs String: mp4a.40.2
    MPEG-4 Audio Object Type: 2 (AAC Low Complexity)
    MPEG-4 Audio Decoder Config:
      Sampling Frequency: 44100
      Channels: 2
    Sample Rate: 44100
    Sample Size: 16
    Channels:    2
```

How `mediainfo` recognizes `Bit rate mode` for `mp4` \ `m4a` ? And is there any way to correct it to `Variable` ?
[image]

P.S.:
Bitrate's plot show that `libfdk_aac` works fine, but output metadata is incorrect - it can't be CBR. Here's example for CBR below (with option `-vbr 0`):

[image]

**UPDATE:**
After an hour of digging this issue I noticed that issue could be solved by editing ESDescriptor.
Here's sample's ESDescriptor that ffmpeg produces:

```
[ESDescriptor] size=5+34
  es_id = 2
  stream_priority = 0
  [DecoderConfig] size=5+20
    stream_type = 5
    object_type = 64
    up_stream = 0
    buffer_size = 0
    max_bitrate = 151870
    avg_bitrate = 151870
    DecoderSpecificInfo = 11 90 
  [Descriptor:06] size=5+1
```

Well, if you set `max_bitrate` and `avg_bitrate` to `0` - `Bit rate mode` magically switches to correct value `VBR` as it is.
So the problem could be solved by using `mp4edit` or by patching ffmpeg (libavformat/movenc.c::mov_write_esds_tag)

Out of curiosity, I checked youtube's videos' ESDescriptor, they also has `max_bitrate` and `avg_bitrate` set to `0`.

Comment: 0 isn't valid value for those fields. Ideal would to calculate actual max bitrate.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that ffmpeg has a bug while writing esds: it writes avg_bitrate instead of max_bitrate which cause decoders think it's CBR audio stream. Somehow if set to 0 works fine everywhere and decoders detect it as VBR. I'm not sure about old ones, but yeah, to be sure every decoder read an audio correctly - better calc actual size.

Comment: As long as the buffer size, when specified, is accurate, what difference does it make?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was caused by ffmpeg/libavformat/movenc.c::mov_write_esds_tag, it can't find max_bitrate. To solve it you should specify audio bitrate `-b:a 128k` along with `-vbr 4`. Then mp4's ESDescriptor would have info about `max_bitrate` and `mediainfo` and decoders would know that audio stream has variable bitrate mode.

Answer (score 0):

Currently only the 'aac_low' profile supports VBR encoding.